# String pooling/interning - Is this good practice?

Tags: c++

As an example, I have a class which I'm storing some information about in binary files:

```
class car {
    char car_manufacturer;
    //other stuff
};
```

Where the value of `car_manufacturer` is one of the values in:

```
enum car_manufacturers : char {
    VOLVO = 0,
    AUDI,
    MERCEDES
};
```

Now in this example application, the user will want a string representation of their car manufacturer rather than a number so I create an array with the string representations of the enums **where the ordering of the array is the same as the enum, so the `car_manufacturer` can be used as an array index**

```
std::string car_manufacturers_strings[MERCEDES + 1] = {
    "Volvo",
    "Audi",
    "Mercedes"
};
```

So now after loading the file and creating a `car` object out of the data, I can get the make of the car, as a string simply by `car_manufacturers_strings[car.car_manufacturer];`

The advantage of this being that, in the files I don't have to store a bunch of repeated strings, if the cars were the same make thus I save a lot of space. But the drawback of this is that the code is slightly  more complex.

So is this good or bad practice?

Comment: You could add a method to your class that does exactly this. Then, the fact that those strings are stored in an array with the same order as the manufacturer enum is an implementation detail that is hidden from the user.

Comment: @MicroVirus This is exactly as I implemented it in my application, the cars being an analogy. I did, in fact, implement the equivalent of `car.get_car_manufacturer_name();`

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty standard practice to provide string representations of enumerators as an array.

One point is that:

```
std::string car_manufacturers_strings[MERCEDES + 1] = {
    "Volvo",
    "Audi",
    "Mercedes"
};
```

Stores string literals in the binary, as well as creates copies of those literals as `std::string` objects at dynamic initialization phase.

You may like to change it to:

```
char const* const car_manufacturers_strings[MERCEDES + 1] = {
    "Volvo",
    "Audi",
    "Mercedes"
};
```

So that it does not unnecessarily create those copies.

Comment: >Stores string literals in the binary, as well as creates copies of those literals as std::string objects at dynamic initialization phase.  I had no idea `std::string` would do this, though in hindsight it makes perfect sense considering `std::string`'s ability to resize and whatnot. Thank you!

Comment: In addition to the use of `const`, which may help the compiler and linker ensure that there's only one copy of this table across compilation units, you may want to consider also marking it `static`, if it isn't a global (globals are always static).  If you use static, you can even hide the array as a private static member in a class in order to make it an implementation detail.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy `const` implies `static` in namespace and file scope.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin:  Sure.  But `static` is how you would mark it as file scope.  Not much context was provided in the code snippets in the question, so it was unclear whether the array was being declared in global scope, namespace (file) scope, function scope, or as a member of a class.  An early comment talked about ways to hide the existence of the string as an implementation detail, and `static` helps achieve the goal in almost every instance, and in the rest it's harmless.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy In C++ unnamed namespaces and `const` make `static` at file and namespace scope unnecessary.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin:  Sure, but we still don't know what context the question was working in.  You're talking about unnamed namespaces, which is only one possible context.  And even in unnamed namespaces, there can be some practical benefits to still using static even though the language standard no longer requires it.

Answer (score 1):

I generally do it with a function, along the lines of:

```
char const * to_string(car_manufacturers cm) {
    switch (cm) {
        #define CASE(CM) case CM: return #CM;
        CASE(Volvo)
        CASE(Audi)
        CASE(Mercedes)
        #undef CASE
    }
    return "Unknown";  // or throw, or whatever
}
```

Advantages:

- no need to convert the argument into a numeric index, so it works with scoped enumerations without need for hideous casting;
- my compiler gives a warning if I add an enumerator without updating the function (not as good as removing the duplication, but at least consistency is enforced)

Disadvantages:

- `switch` may (or may not) be less efficient than an array lookup
- Capitalisation of the enumerators has to match the strings, so you'd have to drop your fetish for `SHOUTY_CAPS`. Some would say that's a good thing; they certainly hurt my eyes.
- Ewwww! Macros!